# Avoid repeating code in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using the same styles of components below on two different components in ReactJS. I wanted to know if it is possible to use a kind of mixin storing in another file and export them, then just call them on each ReactJS component? This would avoid repetition of code.

```
// Repeated styles

const TitleInflow = styled.h1`
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
`;

const Table = styled.table`
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
`;

const ThTable = styled.th`
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
`;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Soluce 1 : You can create a common file like :

**Common.js**

```
const Common = `
 // style you want.
 padding: 5px; 
 color: red;
`
export default Common
```

and add it in your styled components like

**Components.js**

```
import Common from './common'

const TitleInflow = styled.h1`
  ${Common};
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
`;
```

Soluce 2 : You can create a component and extend it :

here a component to extend :

```
const Component = styled.p`
   color: red; 
   fontSize: 12px;
`
```

extend style like :

```
const NewComponent = styled(Component)`
    // new style you want.
    display: flex;
`
```

and if you want extend style with an another html tag you can do like it when you will use it  :

```
 <NewComponent as="h1"/>
```